# What encryption is used by 1password?

Tags: encryption, passwords, password-management

I use a password storage application on my Mac called [1password](https://1password.com/). I was wondering if it encrypts the data it stores on my computer and decrypts it using a key made from my "one password" or if it has the data stored unencrypted but only allows me to access it by first submitting my password. I would hope it is the first way as I feel that this is more secure.

Comment: @mathew  Yes it encrypts using  AES-256 encryption and PBKDF2 as mentioned in https://1password.com/security/

Answer (score 5):

From [the homepage](https://1password.com/security/):

> A potent cocktail of AES-256 encryption and PBKDF2 key derivation ensures that no one but you can see into your data. Everything from your passwords to the addresses of your saved websites are fully encrypted whenever you aren't using 1Password.

So it sounds like they derive an encryption key from you password using [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) and then use it to encrypt your passwords with 256 bit [AES](https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard). (Or perhaps they just use the password derived key to encrypt another key they encrypt your passwords with, to make it simpler to change password, but the security should be the same.)

In other words, it is like your firsst option (but off course I have only read their homepage, not their source code). A password manager that worked like your second option would be a security catastrophe, and I do hope there are none on the market.

Comment: Lol, "from the homepage". Nice, gentle RTFM there.